# context management with mysql-connect cursors

Tags: mysql-python, mysql-connector

I can't seem to get MySqldb to work on a mac, even after so many stackoverflow answers, seemingly one every 6 months or so, thus I'm left with a cursor that has no context management.  So, I tried to make one myself.  This is what I'm trying to get to work:

```
import sqlmgr <-- my class
read_con = sqlmgr.cnx(config_goodies)
with read_con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(account_select, buffered=TRUE)
    temp_d = {i: row for i, row in enumerate(cur)}
```

and this is what I made:

```
import mysql.connector

#sqlmgr connection management for mysql
class cnx:
    #initialize parameters for connection establishment
    def __init__(self,user,password,host="127.0.0.1",database="",charset="",IgnoreError=False):
        self.user=user
        self.pwd=password
        self.host=host
        self.db=database
        self.charset = charset
        self.IgnoreError=IgnoreError
        self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.user, password=self.pwd,
                              host=self.host,database=self.db,charset=self.charset)
        
    #establishes connection to database
    def __enter__(self):
        self.cnx

    #close database connection
    def __exit__(self,ex_type,ex_value,traceback):
        self.cnx.close()
        if ex_type is not None:
            return self.IgnoreError

    class cursor:
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            self.cur = self.cnx.cursor(**kwargs)

        def __enter__(self):
            return self.cur

        #close database connection
        def __exit__(self,ex_type,ex_value,traceback):
            self.cur.close()
            if ex_type is not None:
                return self.IgnoreError
```

which isn't referencing the outside class items correctly since that doesn't exist in python etc.  I was hoping there would be a tool already for this context mgmt stuff, but there isn't, so what's the right syntax.  I expect the answer here would be an example of  how to make this type of class structure context sensitive generally, but I'll leave that question for another day.

Oh, just adding tags, I notices there's this mysql-python tag.  I know I did conda install -c conda mysql-connector-python.  But I don't recall trying mysql-python.  Maybe that's the newest MySqldb item, or maybe it's another python 2.7 thingy.

Comment: python 3.6 and mysql.connector 8.0.18

Comment: If you can upgrade to at least 8.0.21 then both connection and cursor are already context managers.